# Failed to find rosdep libg2o for package rgbdslam

Tags: slam, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi. I want to run RGBDSLAM, but encountered a problem.[Wiki Page.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam_electric)
I've been using the svn to taken out rgbdslam and g2o when I want to compile：rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam
Get the error message:Failed to find rosdep libg2o for package rgbdslam on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed 。
My system is ubuntu 11.10 64 bit
and i try [the website](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) and
when i type :rosdep update.
i got the info:rosdep: error: Unsupported command update.
and the i type :rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg
and i got the info :rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install libg2o

Very much hope to your help.Thank you。

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45995/failed-to-find-rosdep-libg2o-for-package-rgbdslam/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the file manifest.xml, delete the line,

and write,

.

then try to make it.

I assume that you use ros-electric. If so, you can solve only this error by editing as explained above. If you want to really solve the problem, look into file rosdep.yaml

---

Originally posted by [chris_chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2965/chris_chris/) with karma: 84 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1